# What are the eigenvalues of a square matrix added to a diagonal matrix with different diagonal elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have a positive definite matrix $A$ of size $n$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with only two different eigenvalues $d_1$ and $d_2$ on its diagonal. We know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $A$. In addition, $d_2$ is much larger than $d_1$. My question is: does there exist an approximation approach to computing the new eigenvalues of $A+D$?

Comment: There are different algorithms for finding eigenvalues. Your question is not clear.

Comment: When you say approximating, in terms of what data? If you know $A$ and $D$, just compute the eigenvalues of $A+D$ exactly. If you don't know $A+D$, then what do you know?

Comment: I have edited the problem. In fact, I mean that A has been eigen- decomposed.

Comment: if $|d_2-d_1|\equiv\epsilon\ll 1$ you could calculate the new eigenvalues by perturbation theory in a power series in $\epsilon$; $d_2\gg d_1$ does not help, unless $A$ and $\lim_{d_1\rightarrow 0}D$ commute (then you can do perturbation theory in $d_1/d_2$)

Comment: thx. I'll review the perturbation theory.